# JSOM and UTC conversion

Tags: date-time, client-object-model

I'm using client Object Model to filter a list and display an event date.

When displayed I see a UTC date format. How can this be converted to UK date format using Javascript object model?

Is it possible using : `Utility.FormatDateTime` method?

Currently I'm displaying :

```
Wed Dec 10 00:00:00 UTC 2014
```

I require

```
10 Decemeber 2014
```

I'm accessing list using :

```
oListItem.get_item("EventStart")
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Out of the box I am not sure if there is any `Date` format methods are available. You can use something like

```
var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var formatted = curr_date + "/" + m_names[curr_month] + "/" + curr_year;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date

Comment: Hi I've changed the output format. Besides I dont think your code is what I'm looking for. I'm accessing the date from a list using JSOM.

Comment: @OrangeJuice I have updated my answer. In your case you can create `var d = new Date(oListItem.get_item("EventStart"));`

Answer (score 4):

When you get the list item date value you can put it inside of a `Date` object, which will handle the UTC conversion for you; then you have some options on formatting:

**Option 1:**

The easiest from SharePoint is to use the `Date.format()` function provided from the ASP.NET Ajax Date Type Extensions:

```
var myDate = new Date(oListItem.get_item("EventStart"));
var myFormattedDate = myDate.format("dd MMMM yyyy");
console.log(myFormattedDate);
```

Logs something like the following to the console:

> "08 December 2014"

That should give you what you're looking for... The `.format()` function is automatically available on `Date` objects when your browser is viewing a normal SharePoint page -- no need to reference or bring in any libraries. Just be aware when you want to use this on a handcrafted web page somewhere else on the web that it's not part of any base Javascript specifications/implementations.

Here is an MSDN article listing the valid format specifiers and a bunch of examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

---

**Option 2:**

Use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to handle date formatting for you.

---

**Option 3:**

Hand craft the format using `getDate()`, `getMonth()`, etc. as Amal suggests.

---

**Another (less desirable) option:**

You could also use the `Date` object methods that are part of the ECMA Internationalization API standard to get what you're looking for:

```
var myDate = new Date(oListItem.get_item("EventStart"));
myDate.toLocaleString("en-GB", { day: "numeric", month: "long", year: "numeric" });
```

I really can't recommend this route though, because there are some major compatibility restrictions with the [`Intl.DateTimeObject` format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn342822(v=vs.94).aspx)  used above; namely that IE doesn't support it before version 11 and safari doesn't support it at all.

More info on compatibility can be found here: http://caniuse.com/#search=Internationalization